# Updating Product price using Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

i am trying to update product price when product is added to cart

It works and the price is updated but it does not allow me to add any other product to the cart except the product where condition satisfy

below is my code

**cart.php**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Class Cart
 * @package VendorName\Changeprice\Observer
 */
class Cart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        if($product->getCustomAttribute('test')->getValue() == 1){
            $price = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_price')->getValue(); 
        }
        else{
            $price = $product->getFinalPrice();
        }
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="vendorname_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Cart"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Now the problem is, it only allow to add the product when if condition is true

```
if($product->getCustomAttribute('test')->getValue() == 1){
            $price = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_price')->getValue(); 
        }
else{
            $price = $product->getFinalPrice();
        }
```

Comment: Why did you assign $price = $product->getFinalPrice(); in else condition?

Comment: to get the price of product that does not have that attribute values in if condition

Comment: Ohk sorry I misunderstood, did you check exceptions logs?

Comment: yeah nothing there

Comment: did you find below answer working? I think there would be any server logs or can see error in network tab

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the else part at all, try below code with `setIsSuperMode(true)`

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');

    if($product->getCustomAttribute('test')->getValue() == 1){

        $price = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_price')->getValue();
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setCustomPrice($price); 
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: already tried that not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Magento\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Cart implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $price = 10;
        $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```